# Can you define a propositional variable as the negation of another variable?

Tags: logic

Can you have p = not q?

Is there a rule somewhere that says you can't have this?

I'm asking this because there's a question that asks me to prove that all positive formulae are satisfiable. A positive formula is a propositional formula that doesn't have a negation anywhere in it.

But if you can define p = not q then a positive formula p & q would be unsatisfiable.

Comment: I think all the variables have to be independent?

Comment: Can you cite a source please

Comment: If a formula $A := f(p_1, ... p_n)$ where $f$ is a truth-function whatever, is *positive*, it cannot contains $p_i$ and $\lnot p_i$. Thus (by induction ?) you can show that is always possible to define a truth-assignement $v : \{ p_1, ... p_n \} \rightarrow \{ T, F \}$ such that $v(A) = T$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take any "standard" mathematical logic textbook, e.g. :

Dirk van Dalen, [Logic and Structure](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1447145577) (5th ed - 2013), page 7 :

> **Definition 2.1.1** The language of propositional logic has an alphabet consisting of :
>
> *(i)* proposition symbols: $p_0, p_1, p_2,$ . . .,
>
> *(ii)* connectives: ∧,∨,→,¬,↔,⊥,
>
> *(iii)* auxiliary symbols: ( , ).
>
> [...] The proposition symbols and $\bot$ stand for the indecomposable propositions, which we call atoms, or atomic propositions.
>
> **Definition 2.1.2** The set $PROP$ of propositions is the smallest set $X$ with the properties :
>
> *(i)* $p_i \in X (i \in \mathbb N), \bot \in X$,
>
> *(ii)* if $ϕ,ψ \in X$, then $(ϕ ∧ ψ), (ϕ ∨ ψ), (ϕ→ψ), (ϕ↔ψ) \in X$,
>
> *(iii)* if $ϕ \in X$, then $(¬ϕ) \in X$.

With this definition, we have that a single proposition symbol $p_i$ can be a *proposition* but, translating into your terminology, a "complex" expression, like $(p_i \land p_j)$ or $(\lnot p_i)$ is not a *propositional letter* (i.e.a *propositional symbol*) but a *formula* (i.e.a *proposition*).

*Note*. In order to give a positive answer to your problem, we have to modify the above definition excluding $\bot$.

Comment: So proposition symbols can only stand for atomic propositions? What's the shorthand for representing formulae then?

Comment: @user2108462 - what are you meaning with "shorthand for representing formulae" ? Usually, we use meta-variable standing for formulae. In van Dalen's textbook, greek letters like $\varphi$ and  $\psi$ stand for "complex" formulae (members of the set $PROP$) built up from propositional letters with the "glue" of (one or more occurrence of) connectives.

Comment: Okay what if I set p = q? Would p not be an atomic formula then?

Comment: In the above language we do not have "="; we may have $(p_i \leftrightarrow p_j)$ which, of course, is not *atomic* because it is a "complex" *formula*.

Answer (score 1):

No. A propositional variable stands for a proposition that cannot be broken down into smaller pieces.  You could view "$p = \neg q$" as a definition of a compound proposition $p$, or as an assertion relating two propositional variables $p$ and $q$, but not as a definition of a propositional variable $p$.

To determine whether a compound proposition is positive, you need to break it down all the way into propositional variables.  So if $p$ and $q$ are propositional variables, then $p \wedge q$ is positive, but if $p$ is a compound proposition $\neg q$, then $p \wedge q$ is equal to $\neg q \wedge q$, so it is not positive.

It would be less confusing to use different letters (*e.g.* $p$, $q$, *etc.* for propositional variables and $\varphi$, $\psi$, *etc.* for compound propositions,) but I don't think there is a universal standard for this.

Comment: So letters can both represent atomic and compound propositions or they can only represent atomic propositions?

Comment: @user2108462 It's a matter of convention.  Writers should always say what they mean by a symbol and not assume that the reader knows that a particular symbol is meant to represent a particular kind of object.

Answer (score 0):

p&q is logically equivalent to (not q)&q which is not a positive formula. p&q without the condition of q= not p is a positive formula, with that condition it is not a positive formula and thus is not necessarily satisfiable.

Comment: Where is it stated that if a positive formula is logically equivalent to a non-positive formula, then it's a non-positive formula?

Comment: A positive formula (_e.g._ $p$ itself) can be logically equivalent to a non-positive formula (_e.g._ $\neg\neg p$.)  I think it's ambiguous to speak of the "condition" $q = \neg p$.  If this condition is taken to be a definition of a formula $q$, then $p \wedge q$ is not a positive formula because it is _equal_ to $p \wedge \neg p$ (not merely logically equivalent.)  A different, but related, observation is that the _set_ of formulas $\{q \leftrightarrow \neg p, p \wedge q\}$ is not satisfiable.